# how to display image in Mandlebrot tensorflow program.Current output is <IPython.core.display.Image object>

Tags: python, tensorflow

'''Import libraries for simulation'''

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
```

'''Imports for visualization'''

```
from PIL.Image
from io import BytesIO
from IPython.display import Image, display
```

'''Now we'll define a function to actually display the image once we have 
    iteration counts'''

```
def DisplayFractal(a, fmt='jpeg'):

    img =np.concatenate([10+20*np.cos(a_cyclic),30+50*np.sin(a_cyclic),155-
    80*np.cos(a_cyclic)], 2)
    img[a==a.max()] = 0
    a = img
    a = np.uint8(np.clip(a, 0, 255))
     f = BytesIO()
    PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, fmt)
    display(Image(data=f.getvalue()))


sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# Use NumPy to create a 2D array of complex numbers

Y, X = np.mgrid[-1.3:1.3:0.005, -2:1:0.005]
Z = X+1j*Y
print(Z)
#Now we define and initialize TensorFlow tensors.

xs = tf.constant(Z.astype(np.complex64))
zs = tf.Variable(xs)
ns = tf.Variable(tf.zeros_like(xs, tf.float32))


tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

zs_ = zs*zs + xs
print(zs)

# Have we diverged with this new value?
not_diverged = tf.abs(zs_) < 4
```

'''
Operation to update the zs and the iteration count.
Note: We keep computing zs after they diverge! This
is very wasteful! There are better, if a little
less simple, ways to do this.
'''
    step = tf.group(zs.assign(zs_), ns.assign_add(tf.cast(not_diverged, 
    tf.float32)))

```
for i in range(200): step.run()

DisplayFractal(ns.eval())
```

Comment: please add a proper description about the question that you need to ask

Comment: @Surajano hello! its just a program on Mandlebrot tensorflow ( link https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mandelbrot)  would take u their ..I just wanna get how to get the correct output(as an image).

Comment: @Surajano The code is same as mentioned their and their is no error but output is not  as described

Comment: Calling the function `DisplayFractal(ns.eval())` as shown in the tutorial should display an image. If this doesn't work, please explain exactly what you tried and what output you do get.

Comment: @mrry yes! I used that function but still am not able to get an image as output ...final output is  --> <IPython.core.display.Image object>

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki no! thats fine code is running without any error just wanna know how to display an image in output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. You have to run the TensorFlow example in Jupyter notebook:
http://jupyter.org/

If you run it from other IDEs like (Spyder) all you will see is `<IPython.core.display.Image object>` in the console.

Comment: Which means: `pip install jupyter-console` && execute `jupyter-console` then at the jupyter-console prompt `In [1]: ` you just type: `run <PYTHON_FILE>.py`

Answer (score -3):

emmm，I have destroy this problem,you can take a look on my function:

```
def displayFractal(a,fmt='jpeg'):
    a_cyclic=(6.28*a/200.0).reshape(list(a.shape)+[1])

    # emmm I have changed the number. you can just continue your number        
    img=np.concatenate([5+10*np.cos(a_cyclic),15+25*np.sin(a_cyclic),70-40*np.cos(a_cyclic)],2)

    img[a==a.max()]=0
    a=img
    a=np.uint8(np.clip(a,0,255))
    plt.imshow(PIL.Image.fromarray(a))
    plt.show()
```

of course you should import matplotlib .pyplot as plt at first.