# IPython.core.display.Image object can't be displayed in spyder while PIL.Image is ok

Tags: python, image, ipython, spyder, display

I imported the module below:

```
from io import BytesIO
import PIL.Image
from IPython.display import clear_output, Image, display
import numpy as np
```

and save image data to bytesio:

```
f = BytesIO()
a = (np.eye(200)*255).astype('uint8')
PIL.Image.fromarray(a).save(f, 'jpeg')
```

Then display it with:

```
display(Image(data=f.getvalue(), format='jpeg'))
```

I saw similar issue in [how to display image in Mandlebrot tensorflow program.Current output is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227758/how-to-display-image-in-mandlebrot-tensorflow-program-current-output-is-ipython)  someone says spyder just can't do it. But it works well if I use PIL image:

```
display(PIL.Image.open(f))
```

Can anyone help to explain why the Ipython Image object can't work here?

Comment: Please post a full example. In the code you posted the value of `a` is unknown.

Comment: Don't worry, I made a full example.

Comment: With the example I posted above, everything is working fine for me on Linux. So I don't know what happens in your case.

Comment: Thank you, I ran this on Windows. Still don't know why, I changed it to "display(PIL.Image.open(f))"

Comment: I guess the root cause is same as this "It appears that the code example I am working through is specifically designed to use IPython Notebook which is not the same as IPython, or interactive Python."

Comment: I'll test it on Windows and let you know what happens there for me.

Comment: I tested this on Windows and got the same result as on Linux.